# RXJS while loop for pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I try to query all people data from the [swap api](http://swapi.co/). The URL swapi.co/api/people returns an object with an people array and the URL(swapi.co/api/people/?page=2) where I get the next data from. What I want to do is that the subscribe method updates the angular component every time a new page is available.

I’m new to the reactive programming model. How can I implement a while loop or a sequence of Observables?

This works for the first page:

```
getAllPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
    let nextUrl = http://swapi.co/api;

    let source = Observable.create(observer => {

            this.http.get(nextUrl, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(response => {
                    let body = response.json();
                    nextUrl = body.next;
                    return nextUrl != null ? body.results as Person[] : null;
                }
            )
            .retry(5)//send same request based on the url of the previous request till the field next is null
            .catch(error => observer.error(error))
            .subscribe(persons => {
                    if (persons !== null) {
                        observer.next(persons)
                    }
                }
            );

        //observer.complete();
    })


    return source;
}
```

Edit:
I added the retry() method. I hope it is easier to understand what I intend to do. After the first request, it sends more requests to the same URL. Unfortunately, it doesn't use the new URL I get from the previous request.

http://swapi.co/api/?page=1 -> http://swapi.co/api/?page=2 -> http://swapi.co/api/?page=3 -> null

I don’t know how many requests I need to retrieve all data.

Comment: you probably need to use websockets to get notifications about new pages.

Comment: I’m not familiar with websockets but I think it is not what I need. The response of an http get request to the server tells me where to get the next data.

Comment: sure, if you just need to get all pages - you don't need  it but your question was to be able to update "every time a new page is available."

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression. The code above is a service method. An ng component is the observer. The component should be notified(observer.next()) each time a page(part of the data) is downloaded

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By using the `expand` operator you can create a new Observable sequence for each value that is returned. To stop the `expand` from creating any new sequences, once we get a next URL that is null, we can return an empty Observable to stop expanding our sequences. Finally, we can use a `reduce` operator to aggregate the different pages of data into one array that we then emit back to the original subscriber. This can be accomplished as follows:

```js
public getAllPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
          this.getPage("http://swapi.co/api/people/")
            .expand((data, i) => {
                return data.next ? this.getPage(data.next) : Observable.empty();
            })
            .reduce((acc, data) => {
                return acc.concat(data.results);
              }, [])
            .catch(error => observer.error(error))
            .subscribe((people) => {
                  observer.next(people);
                  observer.complete();
            });
    });
}

private getPage(url: string): Observable<{next: string, results: Person[]}> {
  return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(response => {
                    let body = response.json();
                    return {
                      next: body.next,
                      results: body.results as Person[]
                    };
                }
            );
}
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0F5eSoswCfi0dt2pA3r?p=preview)

Comment: Would the results be the same if toArray were used instead of reduce? I'm confused how they differ.

Comment: Normally yes but since the results are already an array you would end up with an array of arrays if you used `toArray()`. Additionally, the reduce method is unpacking the results as well so that it isn't an object but instead and array of people objects.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use expand operator like:

```
function getData(id) {
   let next = id<5 ? id+1 : null;
   let obj = {id:id, next:next}
   return next ?   Rx.Observable.of(obj) : Rx.Observable.empty();
 }

 getData(0)
   .expand(el=> getData(el.next))
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? I am not sure it is going to work as the `getData` function will be called only once. and the result from `getData` will be fed back as `el` to the `expand` operation.

Comment: it will called multiple times till next is eq 5. past the code into jsbin and check. this is called  recursion.

Comment: Thanks Julia, the expanded method (Recursively call provided function) was exactly what I was looking for. The title of my question was not well chosen.